# kubernetes in aks enviroment with nginx ingress 404 Not Found nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a dns mapped to an external ip of my aks load balancer, below the load balancer there is a nginx ingress controller that commicate with an ingress for the services in my cluster.

When I try to access to my dns like: mydns/post/test I receive the nginx 404 error. Seems that nginx answer correctly but doesn'found the internal routing mapping.

Below I rewrite all the step for this implementation.

Installation of nginx by this command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.8.2/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

with command:

> kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx

I see this result:
[image]

I create the ingress controlled by nginx with this yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: post-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

And the post-service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: post-service
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: post
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080


The service communicate with a pod that containt a test endpoint(spring boot app, works
```

correctly tested via forward port):

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class PostController {
    

    @GetMapping("/test")
    String all() {
       
        return "Hello!";
    }

}
```

Why I receive the error nginx 404 error ?

thanks

Comment: Can you update the path in your Ingress resource to match the path you are using i.e. update path: /post . The Ingress resource you've defined is configured to route traffic to the post-service on the path /, but you are trying to access /post/test which could be a reason for the 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your pod logs once using `kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx <your-ingress-controller-pod-name>` to get insights into any issues with routing or connecting to your Spring Boot app.

I can see that in your Ingress YAML, you have defined the path as `/` with `pathType: Prefix`. This means that the Ingress will route traffic with the specified prefix to the specified backend service.

However, when you are trying to access the URL `mydns/post/test`, it doesn't match the specified path in your Ingress (`/`). Instead, you are trying to reach the `/test` path on the `post-service`.

Try modifying your ingress YAML as below

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: service-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /post/test
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: post-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Reapply it using.

[image]

```
kubectl apply -f service-ingress.yaml
```

[image]

requests to "/post/test" will be correctly routed to your service.

Reference Document:

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1336186/ingress-nginx-on-azure-kubernetes-cluster-always-r)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53089294/nginx-ingress-sub-path-redirection)

[Similar SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52021925/kubernetes-ingress-non-root-path-404-not-found)

[Map DNS to external IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267274/how-to-use-dns-in-ingress)

Comment: Great and thanks!!!!