# HTTP Error Code 404 with NGINX routing on AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have a few services set up on my AKS cluster that I'm trying to reach through Postman to see if they work. I am unable to get the current combination of manifest files for my example service to work. Some help would be greatly appreciated! Here are my relevant manifest files.

deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: icap-accountservice
  labels:
    app: icap-accountservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: icap-accountservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: icap-accountservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: icap-accountservice
          image: icapacr.azurecr.io/icap-accountservice:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store-accountservice
              mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: secrets-store-accountservice
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "icap-accountservice-kv"
```

ingress.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: https://icap-vault.vault.azure.net/certificates/ICAP-AKS-CERT/687ed42192e443cdaa9635d5ab67a960    
  name: icap-accountservice-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
  - host: aks.odb-tech.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /accounts
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: icap-accountservice
            port: 
              number: 5000
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - aks.odb-tech.com
    secretName: icap-accountservice
```

podautoscaler.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: icap-accountservice-hpa
spec:
  maxReplicas: 15
  minReplicas: 2
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: icap-accountservice
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: icap-accountservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: icap-accountservice
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

I've tried restarting my cluster multiple times, wiped my previously mismatched deployments and also tried changing around the names in the deployment.yaml to no avail. I've had a look at possible errors with the nginx service, but nothing out of the ordinary pops up. You can try pinging the routes at `https://aks.odb-tech.com/`, specifically GET `https://aks.odb-tech.com/accounts/users`. Directly using the exposed cluster IP also does not work.

Comment: There is a [similar thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77494709/kubernetes-in-aks-enviroment-with-nginx-ingress-404-not-found-nginx), Compare the [IP address](https://i.imgur.com/ERIORC1.png) obtained from DNS lookup with the EXTERNAL-IP of your ingress controller. They should match. If they don’t, you need to update your DNS records to point to the correct IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue was with the request path. The service was expecting the path https://weburl/users, but received https://weburl/accounts/users. Edited the Ingress resource to manipulate the path received by the service:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: https://icap-vault.vault.azure.net/certificates/ICAP-AKS-CERT/
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
  name: icap-accountservice-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
  - host: aks.odb-tech.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /accounts/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: icap-accountservice
            port: 
              number: 5000
  tls:
  - hosts: 
    - aks.odb-tech.com
    secretName: keyvault-icap-accountservice-ingress
```

Note that only the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1` and `path: /accounts/(.*)` matter in this case to fix the URL.